# physical vs. logical core allocation for Matlab in slurm

Tags: multithreading, matlab, slurm

I'm a user on a slurm cluster which is configured to consider each physical core to have two CPUs for allocation. By default, Matlab generates at most one thread per physical core, as Mathworks has determined that there's no benefit for Matlab to utilize hyper-threading. So would it be appropriate for me to request two CPUs per task/parpool worker, even though I'll only be generating half that number of threads? For instance, if I had a job that would use 10 workers, I would say `-c 20`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that. But if your cluster is properly configured, it should know that there are two hardware threads per core, and the output of

```
$ sinfo -e -o "%N %z"
```

should be

```
nodename x:x:2
```

If that is the case, then another way to do that is to use

```
--ntasks=10
--ntasks-per-core=1
--nnodes=1-1
```

That way, the script is more portable ; it can be used on other clusters without change.

Comment: Maybe I didn't state exactly what I'm trying to solve, which is that I don't want to share the cores if it's the case that Matlab is going to fully load them, making hyperthreading not worthwhile. I don't think this solution addresses that, does it?